# Visual Studio 2013 open new files in random order depending on project and file type - how to fix this behavior

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2013 Professional Update 3 with ReSharper 8.2.3 and PowerTools installed.

My issue is that no matter that I've set from Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tab and Windows -> Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs, whenever I open new files they are located randomly on the tab view depending on the file extension and the project where they come from.

How can I make it to always open the new files to the end right position?

Answer (score 5):

After some messing around finally got it to work. The problem comes from the power tools settings which overwrite the visual studio ones.

So if you disable the sorting of documents it's working as expected.

Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> Custom Document Well -> General -> Sorting tab
(I disable both checkboxes -> "By project" & "Alphabetically")

Comment: Works for me with VS2015 Community and Productivity Power Tools.